# How to set ExtraPropertiesExtension in gradle when the desired variant is executed?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I set ext.myVariable as

```
flavor1{
ext.myVariable = "one"
}
flavor2{
ext.myVariable = "two"
}
```

in this snippet.

When i run assembleFlavor1 i want myVariable to be "one". But turns out to be "two". When i change the order of flavors like this

```
flavor2{
ext.myVariable = "two"
}
flavor1{
ext.myVariable = "one"
}
```

it becomes "one" as the result.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using this property? Since a single build can produce multiple variants you'll need to set the property on the that particular variant's build task, rather than globally at the project level.

Comment: Very true sir. And how can i accomplish that?

Comment: I would look at [this section](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manipulating-tasks) of the Android docs on how to get a reference to the specific variant task you wish to modify.